# Getting FB Profile for open graph and changing og:image

Tags: facebook-opengraph, profile, meta-tags

I want to publish an open graph action from an iOS app. The action is giving a gift to someone. I've set up the action with object type profile so I want the action to show on the timeline as "Someone gave a gift to someone else on applicationname" and show an image of the gift instead of the recipients profile image.
Is there a possibility to get the real fb profile with the hover effect and change the image in go:image at the same time?
I tried to use my own website to be crawled by FB and set up all the og tags as needed but if the user clicks on the name of the recipient he receives a warning about leaving Facebook and I would need to redirect to the recipients profile page. Additionally the hover effect on the recipients name would not be working....

Thanks!

Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's been 2 months and no one was able to answer it yet, so I'm gonna go with a different approach since it doesn't seem to be possible...

Comment: Did you ever get to fix this?

Comment: nope, sorry. I decided to do a normal post instead of posting an open graph action since it lacks the ability to have a profile and a custom object or at least a custom image in one action...

Comment: Yeah, what I did was get the profile image posted and get the name otherwise. Profile meta data on facebook would have been a bliss though.